# I have removed the action bar for a specific activity and it is still showing in the preview

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I have removed the action bar for a specific activity and it is working perfectly and the action bar is removed when I run the app on Emulator/Device but the problem is that it is still showing in the preview. Due which It affects my design.

Here is my style file where I set the noAction bar:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <!-- Text Styles -->
    <style name="textStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/theme_color</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="textStyle.tagline">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">46sp</item>
    </style>


    <!-- Button Styles -->
    <style name="button_transparent">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/theme_color</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

    <style name="button_blue">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

I have also applied that style on activities as shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.eapple.karumber">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Splash_Screen" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".protips_activity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But is still showing in the preview as shown here: 
[Android Studio preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY5Md.png)

Comment: Try 2 things. One doing a force refresh on preview. Check the icon marked `1` on this image: https://developer.android.com/studio/images/write/layout-editor-toolbar-callouts_2x.png . When you click on it, the dropdown will have Force Refresh option. Other than that try to do `Build -> Clean` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fastest solution:**

1. Open your activity's XML.
2. Switch to the design tab.
3. On the upper part of the design tab click on **AppTheme**.
4. Choose your new theme (the one with no action bar).

**However**

Adding this line to the activity XML root view should automatically reference to the same activity theme set in AndroidManifest

```
tools:context=".YourActivityName"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I had already done the 2nd option but was not working. 
The first option resolved the heck.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only on the preview u can change the theme with an option on the top of the view. Just select you theme with NoActionBar